# Редактирование ячеек JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Доброго времени суток подскажите, в созданной мною таблице при редактировании ячеек предыдущее значение припадает, каким образом сделать, что бы как в Excel при входе мышью предыдущее значение оставалось?

```
public class PP extends JFrame {
    public PP() throws HeadlessException {
        super("Кадровая работа");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        add(levayaJTable());
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    //Модель основной таблицы
    private JTable levayaJTable() {
        String[] dannie = new String[]{
                "1. Фамилия", "2. Имя", "3. Отчество", "4. Личный номер", "5. Число, месяц, год рождения",
                "6. Место рождения (согласно паспорта)", "7. Серия и номер паспорта", "8. Дата выдачи", "9. Кем выдан",

        };
        JTable levayaJTable = new JTable(new OsnovTable(dannie))
        {
            @Override
            public void changeSelection(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, boolean toggle, boolean extend) {
                super.changeSelection(rowIndex, 1, toggle, extend);
            }
        };
        levayaJTable.setRowHeight(20);
        levayaJTable.setOpaque(false);
        levayaJTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1)
                .setCellEditor(new MaskEditor());

        return levayaJTable;
    }

    //Модель основной таблицы
    private class OsnovTable extends AbstractTableModel {
        String[] dannie;
        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

        public OsnovTable(String[] dannie) {
            this.dannie = dannie;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return dannie.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 0) return dannie[rowIndex];
            if (columnIndex == 1) return data.get(dannie[rowIndex]);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 0) return false;
            if (columnIndex == 1) return true;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            data.put(dannie[rowIndex], (String) aValue);
            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }
    }

    //Создание редактора таблицы
    private class MaskEditor extends AbstractCellEditor
            implements TableCellEditor {
        private JFormattedTextField editor;

        public MaskEditor() {

        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            MaskFormatter dateMask = null;
            try {
                if (table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).equals("5. Число, месяц, год рождения")
                        || table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).equals("8. Дата выдачи")
                        || table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).equals("12. Дата регистрации"))
                {
                    dateMask = new MaskFormatter("##.##.####");

                } else if (table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).equals("7. Серия и номер паспорта")) {
                    dateMask = new MaskFormatter("#### ######");
                }else if (table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).equals("Код подразделения"))
                {dateMask = new MaskFormatter("###-###");}
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            editor = new JFormattedTextField(dateMask);
            editor.setBorder(new LineBorder(null, 0));
            editor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    stopCellEditing();
                    table.changeSelection(row+1,column,false,false);
                }
            });
            return editor;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return editor.getText();
        }

    }

    //Команда выхода из приложения
    class ExitAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ExitAction() {
            putValue(NAME, "Выход");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new PP();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы теряете значение, когда пересоздаете `JFormattedTextField`

```
editor = new JFormattedTextField(dateMask);
```

Comment: Так как выйти из ситуации? Есть возможность установки предыдущего значения после создания?